# Right way to loop and amend an object without re-render loops

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

My main App component calls in a JSON object of venues with their lat / long data.

I am rendering this JSON object out using FlatList and this all works fine. The app is also pulling the device's location so that I can sort this data into distance sorted information.

I'm currently trying to modify this JSON object to add in the distance from the device to the venue and put this back into the FlatList but this seems to be throwing an infinite re-render loop and I don't actually think it's able to trigger my distance checks.

This is my component here. I've commented out the distance work which I thought was the cause but it's still appearing to throw a re-render infinite loop

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";

import * as Location from "expo-location";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import pubData from "../data/pubs.json";

function Item({ id, name, location, alternatives, navigation, sorted }) {
  if (sorted) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate("Pub", {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            location: location,
            alternatives: alternatives,
          })
        }
        style={[styles.item]}
      >
        <View style={styles.itemLeft}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.location}>in {location}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.itemRight}>
          <Text style={styles.distance}>XX miles</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate("Pub", {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            location: location,
            alternatives: alternatives,
          })
        }
        style={[styles.item]}
      >
        <View style={styles.itemFull}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.location}>in {location}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  if (lat1 == lat2 && lon1 == lon2) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var radlat1 = (Math.PI * lat1) / 180;
    var radlat2 = (Math.PI * lat2) / 180;
    var theta = lon1 - lon2;
    var radtheta = (Math.PI * theta) / 180;
    var miles =
      Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) +
      Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    if (miles > 1) {
      miles = 1;
    }
    miles = Math.acos(miles);
    dmilesimilesst = (miles * 180) / Math.PI;
    miles = miles * 60 * 1.1515;
    return miles;
  }
}

export default function FullList({ navigation }) {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [distances, setDistances] = useState([]);
  const [sorted, setSorted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  });

  let text = "Waiting...";
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
    setSorted(true);
  }

  // if (sorted) {
  //   let currentDistance;
  //   Object.entries(pubData).map(([key, pub]) => {
  //     setDistances([
  //       ...distances,
  //       {
  //         id: pub.id,
  //         miles: (currentDistance = distance(
  //           pub.lat,
  //           pub.long,
  //           location.coords.latitude,
  //           location.coords.longitude
  //         )),
  //       },
  //     ]);
  //   });
  // }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.default}>
        Select the venue you would like to find an alternative to
      </Text>

      <FlatList
        data={pubData}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Item
            id={item.id}
            name={item.name}
            location={item.location}
            alternatives={item.alternatives}
            navigation={navigation}
            sorted={sorted}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is the code to blame:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  });
```

You are calling the [`useEffect` hook without a dependency list](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) (second argument).

`useEffect(() => { setLocation(...) })` will fire on every render. You are basically rendering a component, requesting location, and updating state – which (the state update to be precise) is causing the re-render.

If you add an empty dependency list (`useEffect(() => { setLocation(...) }, [])`), the function passed to `useEffect` will fire only on mount, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you a million times!! I'm new to React Native and missed this in the docs. +1 for a link to the documentation explaining this also!

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` in `Fulllist` is being causing the re-renders.

To make it run only once when component is mounted (like `componentDidMount` lifecycle), add an empty dependency array as a second parameter

```js
  useEffect(() => {

   /* your code */

  }, [] /* here */);
```

You can read more in [React docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)